# How to Create DB in Node Js Express Jade JavaScript App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**UPDATED**

I have researched this a lot further. The web application is using the node-db-migrate package. There is a migration folder with two migrations (with table creations). Since I just git cloned it down I am sure I need to run this and I do have node-db-migrate installed on my machine when I hit `npm-list`.

I head into this folder and hit `db-migrate-up` and tried `db-migrate-up [filename]` but I am getting `-bash: db: command not found`.

I am using this with the node-postgres package. It should be loading the `database.json` file according to the node-db-migrate file.

Hi in my data.coffee here is line 1 to 17 as requested, according to the command line it could be the data part that is having problem.

```
uuid = require 'node-uuid'
fs = require 'fs'
_ = require 'underscore'
moment = require 'moment-timezone'
apis = require '../logic/apis'
q = require 'q'

data = (_.chain fs.readdirSync "data")
    .map (filename) ->
        "data/" + filename
    .map (f) ->
        fs.readFileSync f, "utf8"
    .map (p) ->
        JSON.parse p
    .sortBy (json) ->
        -json.intlFormatDateTime
    .value()
```

---

Hi I come from a ruby/rails/sinatra background. I just inherited a javascript web app and I will be rewriting the back end.

I am just trying to start the app locally for now

I did

```
coffee app.coffee -n
```

but I am getting the error below.

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'data'
  at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/judyngai/Desktop/twiage/twiagemed/nodejs/routes/data.coffee:8:17, <js>:16:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/judyngai/Desktop/twiage/twiagemed/nodejs/routes/data.coffee:1:1, <js>:226:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.loadFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:182:19)
  at Module.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:211:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/judyngai/Desktop/twiage/twiagemed/nodejs/app.coffee:3:8, <js>:8:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/judyngai/Desktop/twiage/twiagemed/nodejs/app.coffee:1:1, <js>:76:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

In the app.coffee file there is these three lines of code

```
express = require 'express'
routes = require './routes'
data = require './routes/data'
```

I have installed all the dependencies within the package.json file but there is a database.json file with this line attached

```
{  "dev": "postgres://twiage_db_user:twiage_db_password@localhost/twiage_db" }
```

how do I create this database? normally in rails its a `rake db:create`. I feel like this can solve the problem.

Comment: what's in your `data.coffee`?

Comment: @AndreySidorov Hi Andrey I just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries to read "data" directory which is missing. Does cwd + `./data/` exist? Also, it's common to use path relative to script with [__dirname](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) variable:

```
dataDir = __dirname + "/data"
data = (_.chain fs.readdirSync dataDir)
    .map (filename) ->
        dataDir + "/" + filename
    .map (f) ->
        fs.readFileSync f, "utf8"
    .map (p) ->
        JSON.parse p
    .sortBy (json) ->
        -json.intlFormatDateTime
    .value()
```

Comment: I didn't have a data directory, created one and the error went away also I switched to your way of specifying the directory path